# Call store procedure using java which returns object type

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I call stored procedure from java. which return parameter is object type.

Object type :

```
create or replace TYPE xx_hr_leave_record as OBJECT
(

  employee_name varchar2 (250),
  employee_number varchar2(10),
  Organization varchar2(250)      
);
```

Procedure :

```
  PROCEDURE GetLeaveInfo(p_notification_id IN NUMBER,
                         p_leave_detail OUT NOCOPY xx_hr_leave_record,
                         p_result OUT NOCOPY NUMBER,
                         p_error_code OUT NOCOPY NUMBER,
                         p_error_msg OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2);
```

I am calling this procedure using pl/sql which return properly output.

But I am calling above procedure with the help of folowing link

http://betteratoracle.com/posts/31-passing-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

My Java Code :

```
package com.ind.middleware;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.db.DBConnectionManager;


public class AbsenceDetail 
{
    int notificationId;
    Connection conn =null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt=null;
    ArrayList<String> aryNotificationType = null;
    DBConnectionManager db;
    String qry="";
    String NotificationType=null;
    final String typeName = "xx_hr_leave_record";
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();


    int result,error_code;
    String error_msg= "";


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void getData()  throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            db = new DBConnectionManager();
            conn=db.getConnection();
            if(conn!=null)
            {
                final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName.toUpperCase(), conn);      
                final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();
                cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call APPS.EVO_HR_LEAVE_SERVICES.GetLeaveInfo(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
                cstmt.setInt(1,254163);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.STRUCT,typeName.toUpperCase());
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,Types.INTEGER);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(4,Types.INTEGER);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(5,Types.CHAR);
                cstmt.execute();
                if(cstmt.getInt(3) == 0)
                {
                    Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cstmt.getObject(2)).getArray();
                    System.out.print("data length : " + data.length);
                    for(Object tmpAbsence : data) 
                    {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
                        Struct rowAbsence = (Struct) tmpAbsence;
                        int j = 1;
                        for(Object attribute : rowAbsence.getAttributes()) 
                        {               
                            System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(j) + " = " + attribute);
                            if(metaData.getColumnName(j).equals("employee_name"))
                            {
                                jObj.put(metaData.getColumnName(j), attribute);
                            }
                            if(metaData.getColumnName(j).equals("employee_number"))
                            {
                                jObj.put(metaData.getColumnName(j), attribute);
                            }
                            else if(metaData.getColumnName(j).equals("Organization"))
                            {
                                jObj.put(metaData.getColumnName(j), attribute);
                            }
                            j++;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR in : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []arg)
    {
        AbsenceDetail wa = new AbsenceDetail();
        try {
            System.out.println("Absence Detail class");
            wa.getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really tough to see what you would like to ask. You do say that the procedure is returning the proper output, but then what is the reason you are posting this?

Comment: I have mention that this procedure is working fine in pl/sql not java.  I am not able to call this procedure in java.

Comment: You are of course correct, just a little buried in all the code. However you should post the Java error message or the (relevant part of the) stack trace such that we could know more about the problem you actually have.

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?